# CSS: flexbox container with top & center aligned divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I am trying to create a layout with top and center aligned `div`s.

[image: flexbox layout]

It does work, kinda: [https://jsfiddle.net/zeo29uLa/](https://jsfiddle.net/zeo29uLa/1/)

```
<div class="flexbox-container">
  <div class="top-item">
    top
  </div>
  <div class="center-item">
    center
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  body {
    height: 50vh;
  }
  .top-item {
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: flex-start;
  }
  .center-item {
    align-self: center;
  }
  .flexbox-container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;

    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
</style>
```

My problem and thus question: how to *precisely* make the center div align at the center? Currently there is space above it <=> it aligns below the desired height

I have the feeling that this will be about correct usage of `align-content` in the parent container but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *position* the `top-item` as `absolute` and then add `align-content: center` to the flexbox container - see demo below:

```css
  body {
    height: 50vh;
    background: blue;
  }
  .top-item {
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: flex-start;
    position: absolute; /* ADDED */
  }
  .center-item {
    align-self: center;
  }
  .flexbox-container {
    display: flex;
    background: green;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center; /* ADDED */
    position: relative; /* ADDED */
  }
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-container">
  <div class="top-item">
    top
  </div>
  <div class="center-item">
    center
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I am amazed how flawed this whole flexbox standard still is - this is an absolutely basic type of positioning and the bottom line is: it cannot be done with flexbox. Either you have to do it as shown by you or as show in the duplicate question and use hidden elements - wich is a really ugly hack imho.

Comment: @BM, Actually, it's not really a flaw in flexbox. You just want flexbox to do something it isn't designed to do. Flexbox aligns items through the distribution of space in the container. When there is uneven space, the alignment will be uneven. It's that simple.

Comment: If you're looking for a clean solution, then CSS Grid works nicely: https://jsfiddle.net/zeo29uLa/2/

Comment: I appreciate your grid example - but how will it center the "center" row while making the content of "top" align really at the very top? Basically making the 3rd row the "invisible element" discussed above?

Comment: There are no invisible items in the Grid example. Just the two you have. The layout works by creating a grid with three rows (see the demo I posted). The bottom row remains empty.

Comment: "empty" vs "invisible" :)
But I agree your solution is the cleanest!